# What's format of `en.js` or `ja.js` in lazy load vue-i18n

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-i18n

What's format of `en.js` or `ja.js` in lazy load? below code doesn't work:

```
// en.js
export default
    {
        title: 'Title',
        greeting: 'How are you'
    };
```

and

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import InventoryList from "./components/InventoryList";
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import messages from 'lang/fa';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages
});

Vue.component('inventory-list', InventoryList);

const app = new Vue({
    i18n,
    el: '#app',
});
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include all your language files and assign them to the `messages` key in `VueI18n` init call.

Something like this:

```
import fa from './lang/fa' // relative path
import en from './lang/en' // relative path
...
const i18n = new VueI18n({
 locale: 'en',
 fallbackLocale: 'en',
 messages: {
  en,
  fa
 }
});
```

Comment: thanks but I have error in compile` Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lang/fa' in 'C:\wamp64\www\front-tutorial-example\laravel\resources\assets\js'`. Format of en.js like my question